# How to use anime.js ( or any external library ) in a Vue-Cli project?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli, anime.js

I installed Anime.js with npm as a dependencie to my project.
Now i have a java script file "animate" where I have my anime code.
How to link my component with my animate file to make the magic happen ? 
thanks for reading.

my animate.js file
[image: my animate.js file]

how I tried to link my animate file with my component
[image: how I tried to link my animate file with my component]

Comment: Assuming your animations file is [exporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) an es6 module, you could [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) the animations file into your component file like so: `import 'fileWhereAnimationsLive';`

Comment: @Nora I just tried that and its not working, but maybe now with the edit you can correct me better.

Answer (score 6):

[Anime.js](http://animejs.com) is avaiable at NPM. To use with vue-cli, first install it:

```
npm install --save animejs
```

In your `.js` or `.vue` file, import the `anime` function:

```js
import anime from 'animejs';
```

After that point, the `anime` function/object will be available for use within that file.

Example:

Import the function in your component using `import anime from 'animejs';` (to get references to DOM elements, [**you can use `ref`s**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="go">Click Here to Animate</button>
    <div class="block" ref="square"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import anime from 'animejs';                      // <-- add the import

export default {
  methods: {
    go() {
      anime({                                      // <-- using imported
        targets: this.$refs.square,
        translateX: 500
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[**CodeSandbox demo here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7825o0j9j?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I just wonder in the script tag, methods, what does "go()" do ? Runs the "translate" immediately when component loads?

Comment: On click. See `@click="go"` in the `button`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import anime from "animejs";
export default {
  methods: {
    animatesircles() {
      anime({
        targets: ".banner",
        backgroundColor:"#6c6c6c",
        easing: "linear",
        delay: 800,
        duration:200
      }); 
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.animatesircles()
  }
}
```

Comment: simple as that no need to get a new file